# Como recuperar datos de RecyclerView con evento OnclickListener

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, recyclerview

Tengo un `recyclerView` el cual ya tiene un evento que cada vez que presione un `cardView` me mande a otra vista, pero necesito recuperar los datos que tiene ese `cardview`.

Esta es mi clase `Adapter`:

```
public class TareaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TareaAdapter.TareaViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<TareaObj> tareas;

    FragmentActivity activity;

    public TareaAdapter(ArrayList<TareaObj> tareas, FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.tareas = tareas;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TareaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_card_tarea, viewGroup, false);
        return new TareaViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TareaViewHolder tareaViewHolder, int i) {
        TareaObj tarea = tareas.get(i);
        tareaViewHolder.idUsuario.setText(tarea.getIdUsuario());
        tareaViewHolder.prospectoId.setText(tarea.getProspectoId());
        tareaViewHolder.nombre.setText(tarea.getNombre());
        tareaViewHolder.email.setText(tarea.getEmail());
        tareaViewHolder.telefono.setText(tarea.getTelefono());
        tareaViewHolder.tareaCodigo.setText(tarea.getCodigoTarea());
        tareaViewHolder.descripcion.setText(tarea.getTareaDescripcion());
        tareaViewHolder.tareaTipoClave.setText(tarea.getTareaTipoClave());
        tareaViewHolder.fechaProgra.setText(tarea.getTareaFechaProg());

        final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

        tareaViewHolder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Contacto());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                activity.setTitle("TITULO");

                Log.d("TOD", "ONCLICK");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { //Cantidad de elementos que contiene la lista
        return tareas.size();
    }

    public static class TareaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView idUsuario, prospectoId, nombre, email, telefono,
                tareaCodigo, descripcion, tareaTipoClave, fechaProgra;

        CardView card;

        public TareaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewTarea);
            idUsuario = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etUsuarioT);
            prospectoId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoIdT);
            nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoNombreT);
            email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoEmailT);
            telefono = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoTelT);
            tareaCodigo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoCodigoT);
            tareaTipoClave = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etTareaTipoCve);
            fechaProgra = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etFechaProgramada);
            descripcion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etTareDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

Estuve buscando y encontré lo siguiente:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(nContext,BookActivity.class);
   //pasar datos a la actividad book
     intent.putExtra("Title",nData.get(position).getTitle());             
     intent.putExtra("Description",nData.get(position).getDescription());
     intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",nData.get(position).getThumbmall());
   //Iniciar la actividad
     nContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Pero en un fragment no sé como utilizarlo. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. 
¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para enviar desde tu `RecyclerView` al `Fragment` puedes hacer esto:

```
// Creas un Bundle
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

// Agregas el string o entero que desees pasar recibe, KEY y valor

    args.putString("TEXTO", texto);

// Se coloca este Bundle como argumento en el fragmento.

FragmentInfo info = new FragmentInfo();
info.setArguments(args);

//Una vez haz creado tu instancia de FragmentInfo y colocado el Bundle entre sus argumentos, usas el FragmentManager para iniciarla desde tu actividad.

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer_id, info); //fragmentContainer_id sería el ID del FrameLayout donde tu Fragment está contenido.
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Con esto solo queda recibir la información desde el `Fragment`, esto se hace de esta manera:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentLayout, container, false);

    String texto = getArguments().getString("TEXTO");

    //...

    return v;
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference  me marca ese error u.u Desconozco el por qué

Comment: Ya encontré mi error! muchas gracias! <3 ♥

Comment: Por nada, la idea es apoyar lo mas posible :) saludos!.